# onClicked and onDoubleClicked both happen in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have added `onClick` and `onDoubleClick` handlers to an item in QML, but both of the events get executed when I double click on the area. I don't know if it has something to do with checking if the clicks were generated by right mouse button. Also the order of placing the code does not affect the problem.

```
MouseArea {
    id: idModuleMouseDebug;
    parent: repeaterDelegate;
    anchors.fill: parent;
    acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton

    onDoubleClicked: {
        if(mouse.button == Qt.RightButton) {

            console.log("Double Click");
        }
    }

    onClicked: {
        if(mouse.button == Qt.RightButton) {
            console.log("Single Click");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be a regression of this bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-19940

Comment: But it's not clear because it says "both of the events get executed when I *double* click", which is the expected behavior.

Comment: @cdonts I think it is clear! If I click once, the `onClick` gets called. If I double click, both `onClick` and `onDoubleClick` get called!

Comment: Buddy, calm down. You don't need to shout every sentence. You clearly contradicted yourself when you said "well obviously when I click once, the doubleClick event shouldnt rise!" - it doesn't do that. If you click once, only "Single Click" is printed. That's what @cdonts was pointing out. Also, they are correct: the behaviour is expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @cdonts said, this is the expected behaviour, in the widgets world as well:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
public:
    Widget() {}

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *) {
        qDebug() << "press";
    }

    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *) {
        qDebug() << "release";
    }

    void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *) {
        qDebug() << "double click";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
press
release
double click
release
```

Think about how your expected behaviour would be implemented. In order to not emit the single click if it was *eventually* a double click, you'd need to hold off on emitting the single click until the double click delay/threshold had elapsed, and if no second click came, you'd have to artificially send the single click event late. It would be a mess.

Answer (score 11):

You should use threshold for single click, like that:

```
{
    function singleClick(){
        print("Single click")
    }
    function dblClick(){
        print("Double Click")
    }
    MouseArea {
        id: idModuleMouseDebug;
        parent: repeaterDelegate;
        anchors.fill: parent;
        acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton
        Timer{
            id:timer
            interval: 200
            onTriggered: singleClick()
        }
        onClicked: {
            if(mouse.button == Qt.RightButton) {
                if(timer.running)
                {
                    dblClick()
                    timer.stop()
                }
                else
                    timer.restart()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will result in a visible lag between the time you click and the time the interface responds (e.g. if it was a button).

Comment: @Mitch I know that, but TS wants to split single click and double click (As far as I understand) while double click is always works after single click.

Comment: I hope I never have to use this UI. :p

Comment: @Mitch Wrong! fine tuning the timer provides nice reults you wont notice it

Comment: Can handle it without any delay!! but in qml.

Comment: You guys realize there is no "without any delay" solution right ? Whether it is you or Qt that implements the solution, when a click is caught, the program has to wait and see if it was the first click of a double click or not. Otherwise any double click would fire the click event as well